# Can't Connect to local server using PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have been playing around for PHP with a while. This is how i connect to sql server and it works:

```
$serverName = "SNAME";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME", "UID"=>"USERNAME", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql = "SELECT X FROM myTable";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if ($query === false){  
    echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{
    $ARRAY[] = "$row[X]";
}
```

Server SNAME is on the local network, and i can connect to it from my computer using Sql Management Studio.

Now looking online and other places I have realized PDO is the better way to go. So I have been trying to connect to my server using PDO, by following examples online. Here is the code:

```
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
try{
   $conn = new PDO('mysql: host=SNAME;port=1433;dbname=DBNAME',$username,$password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $data = $conn->query('SELECT X FROM myTable');

   foreach($data as $row) {
        print_r($row); 
   }
}
catch{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When i run this i get this on my page:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it.

Now i know my other information is right since i can use the top block and sql management studio. Is there anyother library or something special needed. Is there problem with my code?

**UPDATE**
I ran this in my SQL Management Studio to check my port and it gave me 1433.

```
SELECT DISTINCT local_tcp_port FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE local_tcp_port IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_connect` is not used to connect to MySQL servers.  It's used to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server.  In your PDO connection string, you're using `'mysql:'`.  You need to make sure the [`PDO_SQLSRV`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) driver is set up and tell PDO to connect to a `'sqlsrv:'` db not a `'mysql:'` one.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one example, you are using `sqlsrv_connect`, but in the other you tell PDO to connect to a `'mysql:'` database.

You need to use the *correct* DSN string for a SQL Server connection.

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=SNAME,1433;Database=DBNAME',$username,$password);
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

P.S. Make sure you have `PDO_SQLSRV` installed.  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: I did have PDO_SQLSRV installed. Thank You very much this works.